# Howto access folders in a Macrium Reflect Image that belong to another user?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, macrium

The following steps were made to access files in a folder that was created with Macrium Reflect on a Windows 7 64 Bit system.

[image: You don't currently have permissions to access this folder.]
[image: You have been denied permission to access this folder.]
[image: You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object.]
[image: Advanced Security Settings for Admin]

In the last dialog I could change the owner and the permission but the mounted volume is write-protected so I cannot close the dialog and apply the changes.

I just want to read them. What do I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a developer of Macrium Reflect, so big disclaimer here, I am talking about a product I am professionally involved in.

Our image mounting code (right click, mount volume) does not allow you to write to your backed up image at all - this includes making changes to the NTFS metadata that allows you to alter file permissions.

However, we're aware that causes problems for folders for which you do not have permission; luckily we've got a workaround for that. From [our knowledgebase](http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50080.aspx):

> The option 'Enable access to restricted folders' will mount the image with full NTFS access rights to all folders in the image. This enables you to fully browse images that were created on another PC where otherwise some folders may be inaccessible due to NTFS security restrictions.

To enable that option, select the checkbox on this dialog:

[image: Restricted folders dialog]

We essentially override the NTFS permissions for folders you cannot access. If you make sure you check this when accessing your image you should be able to access everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have permission to read it, and you can't modify the permissions (because it is write protected), then this is impossible.